# PHP get image size

Tags: php

I'm using the following code but it gives me an error about an unexpeted " in the statement at this line, but I'm not sure how the syntax should go:

```
list($width,$height,$type,$attr) = getimagesize("' . $SESSION_["html_folder"] . '/uploadedfiles/' . $row['logo'] . '");

echo "<p>This logo is ".$width; x $.height; echo "pixels in size.</p>";
```

PHP says the error is on that first line.

Comment: The syntax highlighting here should show you what the problem is. You are opening a string with `"` but not closing it, needlessly as far as I can see.

Comment: its storing `html_folder` in your sessions is what im worried about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
list($width,$height,$type,$attr) = getimagesize($SESSION_['html_folder'] . '/uploadedfiles/' . $row['logo']);
```

The error in your code was that you opened the string "twice", one with " and one with '. If you use a variable as parameter where a string is expected, you do not need to set the variable in quotes.

You should make sure that in $SESSION_['html_folder'] there's no malicious code, e.g. with

```
if(!is_dir($SESSION_['html_folder']))
   die("ERROR");
```

Comment: nitpick: the code is not executable, single quotes are such a tiny reduction in performance, and it will also not read escape characters

Comment: @RobertPitt: the performance aim is not that big, I agree :-) But nevertheless I thought it is worth to say

Comment: No, it doesn't worth. There is no gain at all but only rumor. Call it your favorite coding style.

Comment: @Col. Shrapel: thanks for editing my post, I just wanted to remove the unworth words ^^

Answer (score 0):

youre adding all kinds of unnecessary quotes

```
list($width,$height,$type,$attr) = getimagesize($SESSION_["html_folder"] . '/uploadedfiles/' . $row['logo']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
list($width,$height,$type,$attr) = getimagesize($_SESSION["html_folder"] . '/uploadedfiles/' . $row['logo']);
```

The main issue was that you were using double quotes to open a string, but you didn't close the string with double quotes. The above is a better formated string(and fixed your `$_SESSION` variable).